# How to convert online filled form Into PDF file for printing using flutter or flutterflow

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I want to be able to create an App where the users fill in various information about them and at the end it in converted into a PDF and displayed inside a PDF template using flutter or flutterflow as well as update the information and the edit will reflect on the PDF for download.
How do I go about this or which video can I watch to get a better understanding of it.

I browsed how to generate PDF on flutter but I can't see where they can update or enter information and have it showcased as PDF.

Comment: you can try pdf package from pub.dev